# How to get a history of latest postgres table writes regardless of which table it is

Tags: postgresql

Assume I don't know which tables have been written to (not queries, I mean writes). Can I find out names of tables that were last written to?

Don't want constant reporting. Just a query I can run after testing newly added code.

Once I know the names, I'm set; I can just query them using normal sql and see the records. But need to know which tables in a 200 table database. Something like:

```
select names of last 10 tables that have been written to
```

Comment: Please refer - [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58214/getting-last-modification-date-of-a-postgresql-database-table/168752)

Comment: not possible. Postgres doesn't store this information

Comment: Thanks so much! Will write my own python query. Really appreciate definitive answer.